# Is there any method to callback a function when user click on pagination link in jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables, yui-datatable

I want to call a java script function when user click on pagination link in jquery datatable.

How can i do that?

Comment: In jquery datatable, it showing pagination link like prev,next. When user click on next or previous link i would like to call a java script method. i need to control some ajax request at that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `page` event, which is fire after page changed. Bind `page` event after datatables initialization:

```
$('#table_instance').dataTable({some attributes});

$('#table_instance').bind('page', function () {
    //call some function here
});
```

Comment: is there any way to fire an event on clicks on number

Comment: It working well if you click numbers. Tested with DataTables 1.9.4